# Slave Waiting to reconnect

Tags: mysql, replication, linux, mysqldump, mysql-5.6

I have added new slave host to master for replication, but missing some of the parameters.

```
mysql> show slave status\G  
*************************** 1. row ***************************  
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting to reconnect after a failed master event read  
                  Master_Host: 10.10.2.12    
                  Master_User: slave_user    
                  Master_Port: 3306    
                Connect_Retry: 60  
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000071   
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 754916280  
               Relay_Log_File: mysqld-relay-bin.000001    
                Relay_Log_Pos: 4  
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000071  
             Slave_IO_Running: Connecting    
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes    
              Replicate_Do_DB:    
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:  
           Replicate_Do_Table:  
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:   
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:  
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:    
                   Last_Errno: 0    
                   Last_Error:  
                 Skip_Counter: 0  
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 754916280  
              Relay_Log_Space: 120  
              Until_Condition: None  
               Until_Log_File:  
                Until_Log_Pos: 0  
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No  
           Master_SSL_CA_File:  
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:  
              Master_SSL_Cert:  
            Master_SSL_Cipher:  
               Master_SSL_Key:  
        Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL  
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No  
                Last_IO_Errno: 0  
                Last_IO_Error:  
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0  
               Last_SQL_Error:  
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:  
             Master_Server_Id: 212  
                  Master_UUID:  
             Master_Info_File: /var/lib/mysql/master.info  
                    SQL_Delay: 0  
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL  
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for the slave I/O thread to update it  
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400  
                  Master_Bind:  
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp:  
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp:  
               Master_SSL_Crl:  
           Master_SSL_Crlpath:  
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set:  
            Executed_Gtid_Set:  
                Auto_Position: 0   
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have followed the step below still no luck. I am getting the same error after creating and allowing the user `GRANT` privileges. let me know if we are missing something.

```
mysql> GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'slave_user'@'%';  
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)  

mysql> GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'slave_user'@'10.10.2.16';  
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)
```

Look at this, isn't this strange.

```
[root@host ~]# netstat -tulpn | grep -i mysql   
tcp        0      0 :::3306                     :::*                        LISTEN      2135/mysqld
```

After changing the log position, we are getting this error.

```
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000071',   MASTER_LOG_POS=754916280;

mysql> show slave status\G  
*************************** 1. row ***************************  
               Slave_IO_State: Queueing master event to the relay log  
                  Master_Host: 10.10.2.12  
                  Master_User: slave_user  
                  Master_Port: 3306  
                Connect_Retry: 60  
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000076  
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 488743659  
               Relay_Log_File: mysqld-relay-bin.000002  
                Relay_Log_Pos: 557  
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000071  
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes  
            Slave_SQL_Running: No  
              Replicate_Do_DB:  
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:  
           Replicate_Do_Table:  
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:  
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:  
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:  
                   Last_Errno: 1146  
                   Last_Error: Error executing row event: 'Table   'example.tracker' doesn't exist'  
                 Skip_Counter: 0  
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 754916567  
              Relay_Log_Space: 5112867650  
              Until_Condition: None  
               Until_Log_File:  
                Until_Log_Pos: 0  
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No  
           Master_SSL_CA_File:  
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:  
              Master_SSL_Cert:  
            Master_SSL_Cipher:  
               Master_SSL_Key:   
        Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL  
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No  
                Last_IO_Errno: 0  
                Last_IO_Error:  
               Last_SQL_Errno: 1146  
               Last_SQL_Error: Error executing row event: 'Table   'example.tracker' doesn't exist'     
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:  
             Master_Server_Id: 212     
                  Master_UUID:       
             Master_Info_File: /var/lib/mysql/master.info       
                    SQL_Delay: 0    
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL     
      Slave_SQL_Running_State:       
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400     
                  Master_Bind:       
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp:         
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp: 160127 04:51:22      
               Master_SSL_Crl:    
           Master_SSL_Crlpath:     
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set:        
            Executed_Gtid_Set:       
                Auto_Position: 0          
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Adding the output for `mysqlbinlog`

```
 [root@host mysql]# mysqlbinlog --verbose --base64-output=decode-rows mysql-bin.000089 | tail -n 5 | head -n 1  
ERROR: Error in Log_event::read_log_event(): 'Sanity check failed', data_len: 541414465, event_type: 116  
ERROR: Could not read entry at offset 184469: Error in log format or read error.  
DELIMITER ;  

[root@host mysql]# mysqlbinlog --verbose --base64-output=decode-rows mysql-bin.000086 | tail -n 5 | head -n 1
ERROR: Error in Log_event::read_log_event(): 'Event too big', data_len: -736930139, event_type: 71
ERROR: Could not read entry at offset 668651590: Error in log format or read error.
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20424581/mysql-replication-waiting-to-reconnect-after-a-failed-registration-on-master)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running this command `mysqlbinlog --verbose --base64-output=decode-rows mysql-bin.000004 | tail -n 5 | head -n 1` it gives an error. After investigation we found that last week there was power failure, because of which replication isn't happening. So the workaround is to take a new backup of master and restore the replication.

Comment: I *thought* that command pipeline [looked familiar](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/30538/11651). :)  Note that you need to substitute `mysql-bin.000004` with the actual binlog file you're trying to read.

Comment: Michael that is just an example mine is 000089 which is corrupted.

Comment: Okay, just making sure... you didn't show the error output, so I wasn't clear if you'd had a genuine error or just the error that would have been generated if you had used that as-is with no log 000004.

Comment: Michael I have edited the question. please have a look

Comment: yep, looks like corrupt logs.

Comment: is there any way to prevent the log corruption

Comment: Didn't you say you had a power outage?  If the master server lost power there isn't much you can do, but it's also possible that you have a physical disk issue.

Comment: Yes there was power outage. but still I think there should be something. Now we are planning to have a MySQL cluster. Do you have any suggestion, please let me know