# How do I get the MySQL binary log coordinates from the binary files?

Tags: mysql, replication, mysqlbinlog

I'm attempting to set up replication for a large (120 GB) MySQL database and I messed up.

I shut down the master, copied the data files, and restarted the master. Now I've set up the slave & started it up, and I realize that I neglected to get the `MASTER_LOG_FILE` and `MASTER_LOG_POS` values needed to setup replication.

I still have an untouched copy of the data files. Is there any way to determine `MASTER_LOG_FILE` and `MASTER_LOG_POS` from those files?

**Related question:**

- what happens if you set the `MASTER_LOG_POS` to an earlier point in time?
- Am I correct in assuming duplicate queries will be executed, possibly resulting in duplicate data?

**Edit**

I've been investigating the `mysqlbinlog` command and discovered what looks like the correct info by executing:

```
mysqlbinlog --to-last-log --start-datetime='2015-06-21 20:05:00'
    mysql-bin.000006 | grep end_log_pos
```

The output looks something like this:

```
... a whole bunch more lines ...

#150621 20:10:21 server id 1  end_log_pos 720159843     Query   thread_id=901489    exec_time=0 error_code=0
#150621 20:10:21 server id 1  end_log_pos 720161877     Query   thread_id=901489    exec_time=0 error_code=0
#150621 20:10:21 server id 1  end_log_pos 720162762     Query   thread_id=901489    exec_time=0 error_code=0
#150621 20:10:22 server id 1  end_log_pos 720164796     Query   thread_id=901489    exec_time=0 error_code=0
#150621 20:10:22 server id 1  end_log_pos 720164815     Stop
```

I'm guessing I should use one of those last two positions, but I'm not sure which.

Comment: Did you start mysql on the Slave yet ??? (Please say no)

Comment: Is `mysql-bin.000006` the last binlog ???

Comment: Yeah, I did - like I said, I messed up :-P And yes, that's the last binlog. But let me be clear - this is an untouched copy of the files from the master, completely separate from the slave.

Comment: I know I can fix it if I start over, but I'd prefer to avoid that.

Comment: Question: When you started mysql on the Slave, did it open `mysql-bin.000007` ???

Comment: Yes, it did create `mysql-bin.000007`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25124/discussion-between-rolandomysqldba-and-kryten).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hopefully, you did not start mysqld on the slave yet.

It just so happens that a binlog position is also the binlog size at the end of every binlog event. In your case, you can use the last binlog the slave sees, which I can assume is `mysql-bin.000006`. Get the filesize and use that as the position.

Therefore, on the Slave you would run

```
STOP SLAVE;
CHANGE MASTER TO
    MASTER_HOST='...',
    MASTER_PORT=3306,
    MASTER_USER='repluser',
    MASTER_PASSWORD='replpassword',
    MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.00006',
    MASTER_LOG_POS=720164815;
START SLAVE;
```

and that should do it !!!

I have discussed the binlog position being the filesize before

- `Nov 30, 2012` : [How can you monitor if MySQL binlog files get corrupted?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29585/how-can-you-monitor-if-mysql-binlog-files-get-corrupted/29627#29627)
- `Oct 20, 2011` : [How to handle the My SQL DB Master to Master replication when there was a disk space outage](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6986/how-to-handle-the-my-sql-db-master-to-master-replication-when-there-was-a-disk-s/7022#7022)

You also asked

> what happens if you set the MASTER_LOG_POS to an earlier point in time?

Yes, it will replay those binlog event and cause issues.

Comment: Awesome! thanks for all your help! And thanks for educating me on replication, which is a new subject for me.